Universal Mute Button does not mute Teams
Since the last Windows update, I have a new button in my task bar, the so called 'Universal Mute Button'.

However, when I'm in a Teams meeting, and I press the button, I am not actually muted, my colleagues can still hear me. Even though the tool tip says that Teams is muted. The following text is in German, but it says 'Muted: Microsoft Teams'.

How can I fix that?

What microphone do you use? I'm not familiar with any "universal mute button" but I am familiar with Teams, enough to know it handles sound different from the rest of the OS, in many cases. I wonder if this is a utility provided by your microphone/headset driver?

@music2myear No, it comes with Windows 11, see here
